# open screen in background and start a process

Tags: cron, gnu-screen

I want to do the following: After reboot I want to start a screen which then should execute a script. Therefore I searched for crontab and screen and I also did find some answers. However, nothing works for me. I am running a ubuntu linux with screen installed and I want to run a python script.

The following works `screen -d -m` which opens a screen but does not run anything. Instead, I'd like to create a screen and start a script. From what I found on the net answers told that this is accomplished by `screen -d -m scriptname`. In my case scriptname is main.py (which I checked that it is executeable).

However, `screen -m -d /path/to/main.py` does not create a screen. This is my console output

```
$ screen -d -m /opt/main.py
$ screen -x
There is no screen to be attached.
```

However, this works but does not execute the python script:

```
$ screen -d -m
$ screen -x
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks :)

Comment: What is the console output of `/opt/main.py` without screen?

Comment: It is a print("blabla"). However, I do not understand why this is important. The script works

Comment: Yes, and when the script finishes, screen terminates itself. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Ah, okay. You mean that the termination of the progam automatically quits the screen? Okay, but why does a `screen -d -m` not do the same?

Comment: Nope, this is not the case. The screen is _not_ terminated after execution. I modified my python script such that is take about 1 minute to complete. However after `screen -d -m /opt/main.py` I get again the response that `There is no screen to be attached.`. I do not think that this is reason why it does not work

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It works. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Could you write that up as an answer and accept it? Else this question will return to the front page every now and then and that would be very confusing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `screen -d -m /path/to/executable-python-script.py` works fine.

However, after the script has terminated, the screen is automatically closed. Also, keep in mind that something like `screen -d -m /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/executable-python-script.py` does *NOT* work!

So, use for instance the following python script `testscript.py` to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print("Python3 Script " + str(i))
        time.sleep(5)


main()
```

And then do:

1. `chmod +x testscript.py`
2. `screen -d -m /path/to/testscript.py`
3. Quickly do a `screen -x` to check that the script is actually running